# Email when customer clicks Notify Me on out of stock product

Tags: ce-1.6.2.0, notify-me

Can someone point me in the right direction.

I need my website to send an email to myself when someone subscribes to the product stock notification of an out of stock product. I.e. they click Notify Me, which subscribes them to that products stock status.

I want to know that this action has occurred, with the product details in the email sent to me.

Comment: First of all,for stock alert us must need login in customer account $product=Mage::getModel('catalog')->load($product); $type='stock';//or price Mage::helper('productalert')->setProduct()->getSaveUrl($type);

Answer (score 2):

In Magento there are generally two mechanisms for customizing behavior: event observers and class rewrites. If you are developing a distributed module, you really should use the former. If you are the maintainer of the Magento instance both mechanisms are at your discretion, however, event observers are still preferred as being a bit less invasive in addition to being more future-proof.

The processing method which receives the stock alert request is `Mage_ProductAlert_AddController::stockAction()`:

```
public function stockAction()
{
    $session = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session');
    /* @var $session Mage_Catalog_Model_Session */
    $backUrl    = $this->getRequest()->getParam(Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED);
    $productId  = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('product_id');
    if (!$backUrl || !$productId) {
        $this->_redirect('/');
        return ;
    }

    if (!$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId)) {
        /* @var $product Mage_Catalog_Model_Product */
        $session->addError($this->__('Not enough parameters.'));
        $this->_redirectUrl($backUrl);
        return ;
    }

    try {
        $model = Mage::getModel('productalert/stock')
            ->setCustomerId(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getId())
            ->setProductId($product->getId())
            ->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
        $model->save();
        $session->addSuccess($this->__('Alert subscription has been saved.'));
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        $session->addException($e, $this->__('Unable to update the alert subscription.'));
    }
    $this->_redirectReferer();
}
```

There is a decided lack of events to observe here, indicating that one should next look at the `Mage_ProductAlert_Model_Stock` class for events. Unfortunately, this class doesn't declare a custom `_eventPrefix`, meaning that there won't even be targeted CRUD events (e.g. `productalert_save_after`).

Given that you are looking at a rewrite, you can decide whether to rewrite the model and catch any stock alert activity or rewrite the controller, ideally adding an event. Whereas the existing controller action has all the elements which you need AND your stated requirements match, I would do the latter by adding the following immediately after the `$model->save()` call:

```
$model->save();
//event for hooking this activity
Mage::dispatchEvent(
    'productalert_stock_subscription',
    array(
        'product' => $product,
        'productalert_stock' => $model
));
$session->addSuccess($this->__('Alert subscription has been saved.'));
```

To completely avoid the controller rewrite (in case this is a distributed extension) you would observe the `controller_action_postdipatch_productalert_add_stock` event. In the observer you would need to load the most recent stock product alert by the current customer ID (via session), check that it was very recently saved, and load the product stock data to determine if an email is necessary.